# From where to find default.xml file for jenkins weblogic plugin?

Tags: jenkins, weblogic, jenkins-plugins

As per the document shown [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin). 
I need to provide Additional classpath and configuration file. I am not getting from where I can get the configuration file. If anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You must create it using any text editor. Use the sample configuration.xml found on the plugin wiki as a template. Configure the host names, ports, usernames and passwords to match your environments.